# play audio with jquery .play()

Tags: jquery

I have some audio file

```
<audio id="ID1"><source src="{THEME}/AUPr/AU-1.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="ID2"><source src="{THEME}/AUPr/AU-2.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="ID3"><source src="{THEME}/AUPr/AU-3.mp3"></audio>
```

and I need when i clicked on my button , play this audio . example

```
$('.Button_1').on('click' , 'audio' , function(){ $('#ID1').play() });
$('.Button_2').on('click' , 'audio' , function(){ $('#ID2').play() });
$('.Button_3').on('click' , 'audio' , function(){ $('#ID3').play() });
```

I also try this

```
$('.Button_1').click(function(){ $('#ID1').play() });
$('.Button_2').click(function(){ $('#ID2').play() });
$('.Button_3').click(function(){ $('#ID3').play() });
```

But anything not happen ,
so what would u guy suggest me ?

Comment: Can you please paste your code on fiddle it is easy to us for solving your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.Button_1').click(function(){ $('#ID1').get(0).play() });
$('.Button_2').click(function(){ $('#ID2').get(0).play() });
$('.Button_3').click(function(){ $('#ID3').get(0).play() });
```

`play` is not a jQuery function but a function of the DOM element. You therefore need to call it upon the DOM element

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery object is different from a dom element. You wan the dom element (`$("#ID1")[0]`), not the jQuery object `($("#ID1"))`.

```
$('.Button_1').click(function(){ $('#ID1')[0].play() });
```